# Can I DKIM sign my email without running a server daemon just for that?

Tags: email, email-server, dkim, dmarc, opendkim

I have an email server that is working perfectly.

However, more and more *other* email servers are getting strict about DKIM signing and DMARC records so I guess I need to finally set that up ...

I am running a bind9 DNS server (works perfectly) and a sendmail mailserver (works perfectly).

As long as I can create the keys, is there a way to implement DKIM signing (and DMARC, etc.) *without running another server daemon* ?  I don't understand why I need to run the opendkim server daemon ...

All I am doing is adding a text blob to my emails - why is sendmail not sufficient to do that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A DKIM signature isn't just "*a text blob*", but it has to be cryptographically calculated using a private key and the headers/body that are signed with it. Also, OpenDKIM isn't just for adding those signatures, but for validating them, too. To be more exact, OpenDKIM implements [RFC 6376](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376), [RFC 5617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5617), [RFC 5518](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5518), [RFC 6541](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6541) & an asynchronous DNS resolver that better fits its purposes.

If you take a look at [opendkim.org](http://opendkim.org/) page you'll notice that historically OpenDKIM is exactly how Sendmail has decided to implement the DKIM features.

> OpenDKIM is a community effort to develop and maintain a C library for
> producing DKIM-aware applications and an open source milter for
> providing DKIM service.
>
> The project started from a code fork of version 2.8.3 of the open
> source [dkim-milter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dkim-milter/) package developed and maintained by [Sendmail, Inc.](http://www.sendmail.com/)

This is actually a better choice than bundling it as a feature in Sendmail, as

- not everyone running Sendmail needs DKIM and the added complexity: some Sendmail installations aren't even globally functioning MTAs.
- as a library and a milter other software can use the same features without reinventing the wheel. E.g. Postfix supports the milter protocol.

Comment: Thank you - that's helpful.  Am I correct that the opendkim server does not open any ports, or talk on the network at all ?  That would make me feel a bit better ... I also wonder, if I have sendmail running in a jail and bind9 running in a jail, I assume opendkim should run in the sendmail jail, right ?  bind9 can run in its own server without opendkim, right ?